# PHPMailer unable to attach file using relative path

Tags: php, phpmailer

The contact form I'm working on uses an option to select to upload an attachment through file upload or relative file path located on the server. The first option has no issues, but the second won't work and sends without attachment.

I tried multiple combination but nothing seems working. How would I do this?

```
$mail->AddAttachment("cvs/test-docx_3094.docx", $name = 'test-docx_3094.docx', $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/octet-stream' );

$mail->AddAttachment("cvs/test-docx_3094.docx");

$mail->AddAttachment("http://mydomain.com/cvs/test-docx_3094.docx");
```

any input? Ive been working on this for so long, just cant get it done.

PLMK.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the absolute filepath.

To show what i mean i assume you have the following directory structure:

```
app/classes/mailer.php
app/data/test-docx_3094.docx
app/data/test-docx_3095.docx
```

You could use the following php to get the absolute path in mailer.php:

```
$relativePath = "cvs/test-docx_3094.docx";
$absolutePath = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../data/') . $relativePath;
```

**EDIT**
Considering your comment you have the following file structure:

```
website/
    contents/
        myplugins/
            cvs/
                test-docx_3094.docx 
            phpmailer.php
```

So with this the absolute path would be:

```
$relativePath = "cvs/test-docx_3094.docx";
$absolutePath = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/cvs/') . $relativePath;
```

if your php script is located in the myplugins-folder.

Comment: The obvious I'm not able to dice it. The folder structure is this:

`code`
mydomain.com/website/contents/plugins/myplugins

/myplugins - contain PHPMailer class

/myplugins/cvs - contain the files to attach
`code`

Comment: @r2c3: And where is your code from your question located, where you create a new `mail` and add the attachments?

Comment: Thanks. Find below comments.  

*Using AddAttachment.     

Sending without attachment.     
`$mail->AddAttachment($absolutePath , $name = 'test-docx_3094.docx', $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/octet-stream' );`    

*Using AddStringAttachment. Sending with corrupt attachment.     
`$mail->AddStringAttachment($absolutePath , $name = 'test-docx_3094.docx', $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/octet-stream' );`

Comment: Anyone can contribute solving the issue? PLMK.